# SilverStripe 3: function in controller called within a loop in the template

Tags: silverstripe

I've written a simple custom function to take care of more than (>)
This works fine and returns 1 or 0.

It stops working when I pass $Pos to the function when it's called withing a loop.

SilverStripe Version 3

Controller

```
  function MoreThen($pos, $value) {
if($pos > $value) {
  return TRUE;
} else {
  return FALSE;
}
```

}

Template.ss

```
<% loop GalleryObjects %>
 <% if Top.MoreThen($Pos,2)  %>
$Pos
<% end_if %>
```

Comment: You can create a custom template iterator:

[$Pos from bottom inside <% loop DataObjects %>][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096216/pos-from-bottom-inside-loop-dataobjects

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK it is not possible to use variables as arguments of function calls, only concrete values. Depending on what you want to do, you might want to look at using GalleryObjects.limit() in your template, or write a specific getter that would return only GalleryObjects with an offset greater than 2. Hope this helps

Comment: All I wanted to is display a different size image if the object position is more than 2. I've just added <% if $Pos == 3 || $Pos == 4 || $Pos == 5%>. Not very clean.

Comment: Maybe a slightly less dirty solution would be to  use <% if $Pos != 1 && $Pos != 2 %><% else %> ... <% end_if %>. This would have the advantage of working for image position >=6