# How to get second to last item in loop

Tags: silverstripe

Silverstripe has helpers for getting the first and last items in a loop as well as the position / count of the current item in the loop.

Though I can't find how to capture when it's the second to last item...

I've tried trivial things (*that'd usually work in most languages*) such as

```
<!-- Right now I know the total is 11, so result should be 10 -->
<!-- Total value will always vary so needs to be dynamically worked out -->

<% if $Pos == $TotalItems-1 %>
    $Pos
<% end_if %>

     &&

<% if $Last-1 %>
    $Pos
<% end_if %>
```

This doesn't work, AFAIK unlike JavaScript or PHP or whatever you can't slap a -1 to get the second to last item in a loop / array.

What would I need to do to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `$FromEnd` for that. It will return the distance to the end of a list. By default, this starts with `1`, the same way as `$Pos` does. So the last item in a list is `$FromEnd == 1`. The second last item in a list would be `$FromEnd == 2`.

You can also pass the start index as a parameter to the function, so this would also select the second last item: `$FromEnd(0) == 1`.

In your template, this would look like this:

```
<% if $FromEnd(0) == 1 %>
<%-- conditional stuff for the second-last item --%>
<% end_if %>

<% if $FromEnd(0) < 2 %>
<%-- conditional stuff for the two last items in a list --%>
<% end_if %>
```

Generally, I almost never use these methods. If it's related to properly format items, I advice to use CSS instead (eg. `nth-child`, `nth-last-of-type` etc.).

Comment: Wicked! May I ask where you found out about this? Have never seen it in the docs. Regarding the last bit - I too CSS everything where ever possible but I'm using this to create multiple containers within a single loop and spread data across them; so this isn't something CSS would be ideal for as I'm working with the actual structure of the template, not the style of it.

Comment: @Freemium Ah I see. I've looked at the API of [`SSViewer_BasicIteratorSupport`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/class-SSViewer_BasicIteratorSupport.html). The more complex approach would have been to add your own `TemplateIteratorProvider`

Comment: for the later @bummzack mentioned see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096216/pos-from-bottom-inside-loop-dataobjects

Answer (score 0):

Tnks! And it also worked for me...

```
<% if $FromEnd(0) != 0 %>
    <%-- conditional stuff for all items but the last one in a list --%>
<% end_if %>
```